# Mockito it's instantiating with null the builder in the mocked class

Tags: java, mockito, spring-boot-test, spring-boot-3

After migrate from Java 11 to 17 and Springboot 2 to 3, a test start to fail with NPE.
After some investigation I found this mock instance give me a NPE in the builder:

Tracer interface is -> import io.micrometer.tracing.Tracer;

Tracer its an interface from micrometer package.

@Mock
private Tracer tracer;

tracer.traceContextBuilder().traceId(XXX).build();

In this case traceContextBuilder is null.

I'm using mockito-core:5.7.0.
An this are my test dependencies:

```
testImplementation 'org.junit.platform:junit-platform-launcher:1.5.2'
testImplementation 'org.junit.platform:junit-platform-runner:1.5.2'
testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
testImplementation group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.+'
```

Previously I can use this without a NPM. It's there any way to generate a mock with this traceContextBuilder not in null state?

I'm preety new at Mockito. Is there any way to initialize a Mock with not null parameters (like a new object or something).
Or maybe I need to instanciate the object and use an @Spy annotation?
A more general question it's. Can I instantiate Mock with all the fields availables? Like a real object?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMHO the best option here is to not use Mockito here at all. Micrometer's [`Tracer` interface](https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/tracing/blob/main/micrometer-tracing/src/main/java/io/micrometer/tracing/Tracer.java) already defines a dummy noop Tracer that can be used in tests:

```
private Trace tracer = Tracer.NOOP;
```

No mock setup and everything just works™ in your tests: the tracer does nothing, which is usually want you want from the tracer in your test.

---

If you really must to do this with Mockito, continue reading.

Mockito mocks by default return a default value for any given return type. That is `false` for booleans and Booleans, `0` for numeric types (primitive or boxed), empty collections and empty maps for collection and map types, `empty()` for Optionals, `null` for Strings and other Objects. (I think there are a few more, such as `AtomicReference`, which returns an `AtomicReference(null)`).

Since you have not stubbed your mock to return a non-default answer, it will simply return the default as described above; in your case `null` for complex objects.

You have at least two options to solve this with Mockito:

1. Stub all calls that you expect

```
@Mock private Tracer tracer;
@Mock private TraceContext.Builder traceContextBuilderMock;

when(tracer.traceContextBuilder()).thenReturn(traceContextBuilderMock);
when(traceContextBuilderMock.traceId(anyString())).thenReturn(traceContextBuilderMock);
tracer.traceContextBuilder().traceId(XXX).build();
```

2. Mock with `Answers.RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS`

```
@Mock(answer = Answers.RETURN_DEEP_STUBS) private Tracer tracer;
tracer.traceContextBuilder().traceId(XXX).build();
```

Comment: You are right. I don't need to mock the Tracer if I instantiate it as you show.
Anyway, I still need to use it like a mock to check interactions. So I annotate it with @Spy to do the trick.
Thanks a lot for this new perspective knittl, you save my day :)!